# Using async/await with a for..of loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have using await in for...of loop, but it can't be stopped at await function and returned directly. Does anyone meet this problem?
dataTemplate is an object.

```js
async dataAssign(dataTemplate: object, paramList: Array < any > , param: object) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(dataTemplate)) {
    if (typeof (dataTemplate[key]) === 'string' &&
      !this.validationService.isNullOrEmpty(param[dataTemplate[key]])) {
      dataTemplate[key] = await this.cryptoService.encrypt(this.constantService.securityPasswordKey, param[dataTemplate[key]]);
      console.log(dataTemplate[key]);
    } else if (typeof (dataTemplate[key]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(dataTemplate[key])) {
      this.dataAssign(dataTemplate[key], paramList, param);
    } else if (Array.isArray(dataTemplate[key]) && dataTemplate[key].every(element => {
        return typeof (element) === 'object'
      })) {
      for (const childKey in dataTemplate[key]) {
        this.dataAssign(dataTemplate[key][childKey], paramList, param);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: “it can't be stopped at await function and returned directly” — This isn’t clear.

Comment: You're not awaiting in all conditions.  You'll find that if you are hitting the `await` in the loop, it will wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL:DR

**You need to await the recursive calls to `this.dataAssign` as it's an async
function.**

#### Some notes

- you could use `Object.entries` in the first `for...of` loop. that way you you don't always have to use `dataTemplate[key]`. tends to be a little easier/more readable
- when checking for `typeof <value> === 'object'`, you might want to include a null-check. Because of legacy reasons, `typeof null` is 'object' and this can lead to some nasty errors when not considered.
- do NOT use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an array, always use a `for...of` or `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loop. It's not too uncommon to add properties to an array. And a `for...in` loop will also retrieve these, possibly leading to unwanted behaviour.

  - ex:

    ```js
    const string = 'Molestiae labore sunt et. Cum quisquam nam et labore voluptatem vel alias.'
    const regex = /labore\s(\w+)\set/
    const arr = string.match(regex)
    console.log('-- IN --')
    for (const key in arr) console.log('- ' + arr[key])
    console.log('\n-- OF --')
    for (const item of arr) console.log('- ' + item)
    ```

    will log:

    ```
    -- IN --
    - labore sunt et
    - sunt
    - 10
    - Molestiae labore sunt et. Cum quisquam nam et labore voluptatem vel alias.
    - undefined

    -- OF --
    - labore sunt et
    - sunt
    ```

So it could look something like this:

```
async dataAssign (dataTemplate: object, paramList: any[], param: object) {
  // using `Object.entries` to directly get a `[key, value]` touple to work with
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataTemplate)) {
    // I'm using a switch here because i find it easier to read, but
    // there's nothing wrong with using `if` - `else if`
    switch (typeof value) {
      case 'string':
        if (this.validationService.isNullOrEmpty(param[value])) break
        dataTemplate[key] = await this.cryptoService.encrypt(this.constantService.securityPasswordKey, param[value])
        break
      case 'object':
        // null-check
        if (value !== null) break
        if (Array.isArray(value) && value.every(element => typeof element === 'object' && /* null-check */ element !== null)) {
          // do NOT use `for...in` to iterate over an array, use `for...of` or `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`
          for (const childValue of value) {
            // you need to await this recursive call
            await this.dataAssign(childValue, paramList, param)
          }
        } else {
          // you need to await this recursive call
          await this.dataAssign(value, paramList, param)
        }
        break
      // not nescessary. if you prefer it to silently drop non-matches this can be stripped
      default:
        throw new Error('invalid template')
    }
  }
}
```